# Power OFF then ON an ESP8266 when GPIO0 go low (aka reset ESP without nRST pin)

Tags: esp8266, programmer, nrst

I need to flash some ESP8266 based devices that does not have the nRST pin accessible, but only:
VCC, GND, RX, TX, GPIO0

As programming board I'm using an old NodeMCU board that has this auto-programming circuit:

[image]

Due to the nRST pin is not accessible, by now before start programming I perform these steps:

1. disconnect VCC
2. bridge-connect GPIO0 to GND
3. reconnect VCC
4. programm
5. disconnect VCC
6. remove GPIO0-GND jumper
7. reconnect VCC
8. normal running

This is a very time consuming task, how can I make a simple circuit to do this?
Do a NPN transistor acting like switch on VCC and driven by nRST do the trick?

Comment: what devices are these?

Comment: You're mixing up RTS and RST.  You can't use an NPN; you could use a high side switch but formally would need something like a level translator to block signals to the depowered ESP.  Without that it would be out of spec but might work anyway...